# How to close an archived Outlook .pst files in .NET?

Tags: .net, outlook

I can use the following VB code to open an Outlook .pst file

```
Dim olApp As Application = New Application()
Dim oNS As [NameSpace] = olApp.GetNamespace("mapi")
Dim sStore As String = "[path to .pst file]"
oNS.Session.AddStore(sStore)
' do something - read messages, whatever 
'oNS.Session.RemoveStore(sStore)
olApp.Close
olApp.Dispose
```

NB: sStore is a path to an archived .pst file and is not open in Outlook itself.

This works... however, before running it I close Outlook (normally running on my PC). Then, after running this code, on re-opening Outlook I see that the .pst file has been added/opened and is there to be viewed in Outlook.

What I want to do is close it in the code so that it is not in Outlook when I re-open that. I imagined that the commented out line
'oNS.Session.RemoveStore(sStore)
would do this, but it doesn't - and in fact Visual Studio's intellisense flags a potential error with it telling me that the expected argument for RemoveStore is an Outlook folder, not a string. (For AddStore it's just an Object). Seems strange to me (ignoramus that I be) - why is it a folder? Anyway, grateful for any clues about removing the entire "store".

(I've used VB code here, but am OK with C#)

- update -

To clarify: my Outlook has one .PST file (for my IMAP/POP3 accounts) and two Exchange accounts. With the code I am on about I want to temporarily open another .PST file.

Following Dimitri's comment below, I tried the line

```
oNS.Session.RemoveStore(CType(olApp.Session.Stores(olApp.Session.Stores.Count - 1).GetRootFolder(), Folder))
```

What Dimitri suggests can't be done, as sStore is just a String, so I tried using the root folder of the last added olApp.Session "store".

This produced unexpected results, and not even consistent ones. (On one occasion my default .pst files was removed!) SO I tried logging, just to see

```
Dim r As Integer
Dim sb As New StringBuilder
For r = 0 To olApp.Session.Stores.Count - 1
   sb.AppendLine(olApp.Session.Stores(r).FilePath)
Next
```

and on different runs I get the paths listed in a different order! And, for some reason, the file path to my just last added store doesn't even get listed, except there is a blank line added. ??

So... I guess what I need is a way to know what "r" in the iteration loop corresponds to the .pst file I want to remove. Maybe just look for a blank FilePath, but this seems rather crude and prone to unexpected consequences - there must a proper way to do this.

Comment: Try to replace that line with `'oNS.Session.RemoveStore(sStore.GetRootFolder)`

Comment: Thanks Dimitri, but... see my update.

Comment: The newly added store is not guaranteed to be last in the Stores collection. But you are on the right track - loop through the stores and compare FilePath to sStore.If the two match, remove the store and break out of the loop.

Comment: Ta, but as I said in my update, I don't see the FilePath to my added store in the at all - I don't understand why, but it's not there.

Comment: Are you saying FilePath is always empty? Is that what you see in OutlookSpy if you click Namespace button, select Stores property, click Browse, go to the IEnumVariant tab, double click on the new store, and select Store.FilePath property?

Comment: Never used that s/w (first I've heard of it, in fact. It looks good, but not sure I need it bad enough...) - but IDK why the FilePath should be empty, though it is. But to open it in Outlook I (of course) have to browse to the .pst file on my computer. The other FiePaths aren't empty, ie for the default .pst file I use, and the two Exchange boxes I also have. It's only the one I add via this little bit of code I'm having the issue with.

Comment: FilePath will be empty for online stores or stores other than Exchange or PST. Just trying to check whether the problem is in OOM or in your code when you retrieve the store.

Comment: The FilePath to the default .pst file is listed (which is not the usual install directory, but in a custom location of my choosing), The one I'm trying to open in my code is also a .pst file - each year I archive the previous "default" .pst and create a new (empty) one. The one I am trying to open in code is a previous year's .pst.

Comment: So do you see the file path of that PST file

Comment: I see the FilePath of the "!default" outlook.pst that my instance of Outlook uses for my IMAP/POP3 accounts. But after loading an archived .pst file via my code and then iterating through the "stores", I do not see the FilePath of this just loaded one - I only see the default one that is there all along.

Comment: There is also an extraneous blank line - as though the iteration loop has seen the store, but for some reason can't see its FilePath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop is wrong - all OOM collections are 1 based, not 0. It must be

```
Dim r As Integer
Dim sb As New StringBuilder
For r = 1 To olApp.Session.Stores.Count
   sb.AppendLine(olApp.Session.Stores(r).FilePath)
Next
```